# data-icon attribute not working with jquery mobile alpha 4 verion

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

This code snippet is taken from jquery mobile demo page:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="delete">Cancel</a>
    <h1>Edit Contact</h1>
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="check">Save</a>
</div>
```

I expect a "x" mark in the Cancel button and a check mark in the Save button.But I cannot see the icons,but only text,that is Cancel and Save.

I am using jquery mobile alpha 4:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
```

I tested this in Google Chrome 10.0.648.127

Am I missing something here?

Comment: First I would upgrade to the beta version, Second I think you're using a older version of jQuery. I think a4.1 uses 1.5.x not 1.4.x

Comment: Used the latest version of jquery and jquery mobile and the issue is now fixed.Thanks.Now,if you could please post the comment as an answer I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would upgrade to the beta version, Second I think you're using a older version of jQuery. I think a4.1 uses 1.5.x not 1.4.x